# How to repair boot cover sticking out?

Tags: body-work

Boot lid is outright sticking out on one end.  If I pressure the top it goes down but comes back up when I stop holding it.  how can i get it down?

[image]

Comment: Detail of "how" this happened - even just "parked it and it was fine, returned and it was like that" would give us a clue or could be had body repairs done which means they may have left fixings loose OR **you** tried adjusting the panel gap and got it wrong...

Comment: Well somebody pointed it out to me, prior to which I have never noticed.

Comment: If you never noticed that, I wonder what the other panel gaps are like... "fits where it touches"...

Answer (score 1):

I do have to ask.. what caused that issue?  Was the vehicle ever involved in an accident?

Generally, that can be adjusted with a wrench.  The mechanism which controls that motion has should have slots designed to allow for some adjustment. Each 'hinge' will have four bolts or screws, two on the deck, and two on the sheet metal body.  You'll have to inspect things carefully to understand the adjustment slots.

If vehicle is new, never been in an accident, and still under warranty, I'd bring it back to the dealer. When adjusted correctly, the decklid surface should be flush, or slightly subflush to the quarter panel.

Note there are three places that affect the decklid mounting.. two 'hinges' (left and right) and the decklid latch.  All three of those may have to be adjusted / coordinated so the system looks right.

Note: it's totally possible that the hinge mechanism is bent.  They can easily be adjusted by bending, but be doggone careful that you don't dent the visible sheet metal.